# Windows OS commands are not executing in Spring Shell

Tags: java, spring-shell

I am using spring shell to develop command line interface application, I am facing one issue in windows machine, On Linux machine i am able to execute OS commands by using `!<OS Command>`,
but this is not working in windows machine. Spring shell says

`Unable to execute command, The system can not find the specified command`.

Please let me know how can i execute windows command in Spring shell running in windows platform( commands like date, time,path etc)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

date, time, path, etc. are built-in commands of the windows command shell. It seems that these built-in commands are not available within spring-shell and spring-shell looks after commands which exist real as file in the windows path.

Windows-Commands like calc (`! calc`) which are not built-in are available.